# Zip Excel sheet generated through gem axlsx rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I'm facing an issue of how to zip the excel sheet generated through gem 'axlsx_rails'. For example:

```
class SampleController < ApplicationController::Base

  def export
    if params[:zip]
        xxxx
    else
      render xlsx: 'export', filename: filename, disposition: 'attachment'
    end
  end

end
```

In the above example, right now the end user is able to download the excel sheet but if the end user requests a zip file of excel sheet, how can we do that. Because of code in 'else' block the end user is able to download the excel sheet. What I have to do if the user wants the excelsheet to be zipped before download. If you need any further info, plz let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested code, but try using `Zip::ZipOutputStream`:

```
def export
  if params[:zip]
    compressed_filestream = Zip::ZipOutputStream.write_buffer do |zos|
      content = render_to_string xlsx: 'export', filename: filename
      zos.put_next_entry(filename)
      zos.print content
    end
    compressed_filestream.rewind
    send_data compressed_filestream.read, filename: 'export.zip', type: 'application/zip'
  else
    render xlsx: 'export', filename: filename, disposition: 'attachment'
  end
end
```

If it doesn't work, create an issue on Github, and after we get it working we can add it to the documentation.

Comment: Thanks Noel. It worked for me but i refactored the code little bit to suit my app

Comment: If you get AbstractController::DoubleRenderError try to put `self.response_body = nil` after `render_to_string`. This helped me. I am using Rails 4.2.5